# Why java int type has valid value in range -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647?

Tags: java, primitive-types

I'm wondering why java int type (32 bit signed) has valid value in range -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 but not in (-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,648)?

Comment: Because 0 is a number as well. If you count all of them you will see that that's how many fit in 32 bits.

Comment: [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: Related: [What is “2's Complement”?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1049722)

Comment: This means out of memory to allocate and represent 2,147,483,64? Right?

Comment: no, it just means that it requires more than 32 bits (assuming two's complement representation of 2_147_483_648)

Comment: Assume a 2 bit integer. 00 = 0, 01 = 1; 10 = -2, 11 = -1. With two's complement, the absolute value of the most negative number is one larger than the most positive number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary representation of numbers in *modern* computers is some form of binary representation.  It consists of a fixed number of bits that take the values 0 or 1.  In Java, an `int` is *specified* to use a binary representation with 32 bits.

A 32 bit binary representation can have 2^32 states.  (This is a mathematical fact.  It can be proven from first principles.)

Consider the mathematical integers from -2^31 to +2^31:

- There are 2^31 numbers in the range 1 to 2^31 (inclusive)
- There are 2^31 numbers in the range -1 down to -(2^31) (inclusive)
- The value zero is not in either of the above ranges.

So counting the numbers from -2^31 to +2^31, we get a total of 2^31 + 2^31 + 1 values.  That is 2^32 + 1 which is more values than can be represented in 2^32 states.

What you are suggesting is not mathematically possible.